# How to get value from 1st panel and insert in 2nd panel in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I had employ name Text Field in 1st panel in D module. when i click generate button the employ name automatically update in display panel Employe Name Textfield in E module. so in both the panels the value must be same. how can i get the value from D module and update in E module by using Java Swing.

Comment: You might post a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example (sscce) that illustrates the problem. http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1):

Swing relies heavily on the Obeserver pattern.  You can use this pattern to help your E module know when the generate button is clicked.

If your E module has a reference to your D module, you can add E as an `ActionListener` to the generate button.  You can then pull the text from the D module when the action is fired.  A brute-force approach is mapped out below:

```
public class DModule {
     private JButton genButton = new JButton("generate");
     private JTextField empNameTF = new JTextField();      

     // ---more code ---  


     public void addGenButtonListener (ActionListener l) {
          genButton.addActionListener(l);
     }

     public String getEmpName() {
          return empNameTF.getText();
     }
}


public class EModule implements ActionListener {
     DModule d = null;
     JTextField myEmpNameTF = new JTextField();

     public EModule (DModule d) {
          this.d = d;
          d.addGenButtonListener(this);
     }

     // --- more code ---

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
          myEmpNameTF.setText(d.getEmpName());     
     }

}
```